# Current waveform for LTE transmit

Tags: power-supply, radio, lte

I am designing an IoT system which uses the SIM7000A. In the SIM7000 series datasheet it says that the highest possible current for LTE is under 200mA (*section 5.4* of *SIM7000 Hardware Design_V1.03*). However, it provides no other information - like what the waveform will be or its duration.

I am transmitting an HTTP GET. For how long will this consume 200mA of current? Will the waveform be a constant 200mA during the transmission or will it be a series of square waves? I don't have an oscilloscope so I can't check for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Only your scope will know for sure.  Use a PC audio port to measure with free SCope S/W

This is all I could find. YOu have to count bytes for the GET.

[image] 
 [image]